# CSS & JQuery: Better Usability

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to improve my user experience of the following code:

HTML:

```
<div class="news-item">
    <div class="main-content">
        <div class="header"> Header 1 </div>
        <div class="content"> lorum ipsum </div>
        <div class="time"> time </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="news-item">
    <div class="main-content">
        <div class="header"> Header </div>
        <div class="content"> lorum ipsum </div>
        <div class="time"> time </div>
    </div>
</div>​
```

JavaScript:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $(".header").click(function () {
      $(this).parent().toggleClass("expand");
    });
});​
```

CSS:

```
body {
    background-color: whitesmoke;
}

.header{
    font-size: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    cursor:pointer;
}

.main-content {
    margin: 0 0 12px 70px;
    padding: 0;
    background: rgb(251, 251, 251);
    width: 80%;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.35);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
    position:relative;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    background-color: white;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 22px;
    height: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.expand {
    height: 200px;
}​
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/9UJ7f/4/

As you may notice, when you click the Header, the box expands or collapses.

However, this only works when we click the Header, e.g. when we click the box's border (in collapsed mode) nothing happens.

To eradicate "void-clicks", I would like it to be like this:

A. In Collapsed Mode:
If you click anywhere on the box (.main-content class), the item will expand

B. In Expanded Mode:
If you click only the .Header class, the item contracts again.

What would be the best approach to do this ?

## UPDATE:

OK, you were right. The CSS was a bit off.
I choose sandeep's solution as it was the most minimalistic but best working solution.
But also thanks to everyone else who helped. Especially the JS solutions from thecodeparadox & Arif. (though it still has some "void clicks" around the border).
You are awesome, guys. I'll give you all a thumbs up.

Comment: I tried this approach: The classToggle works, but strange enough, the click also get's executed when the class .clickable is not there.
Looks like a bug in jquery to me:
http://jsfiddle.net/9UJ7f/10/

Comment: You could also improve it by adding a pointer cursor when the box is collapsed. (for the .main-content) And remove it when it is expanded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give padding to **heading** DIV. Write like this:

```
    .main-content {
        margin: 0 0 12px 70px;
        padding: 0;
        background: rgb(251, 251, 251);
        width: 80%;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
        -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.35);
        box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
        position:relative;
        margin-left: 20px;
        margin-top: 20px;
        background-color: white;
        -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
        -moz-border-radius: 5px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        padding-bottom: 22px;
        height: 42px;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    .header  ~ div{
        margin:22px;
    }

    .header{
        font-size: 20px;
        padding: 22px;
        cursor:pointer;
    }
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/9UJ7f/14/

Answer (score 2):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $('.header').click(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        $(this).parent().toggleClass('expand');
    })
    $(".main-content").click(function() {
        if (!$(this).hasClass('expand')) {
            $(this).addClass("expand");
        }
    });
});
```

**[Perfect working sample](http://jsfiddle.net/thecodeparadox/9UJ7f/22/)**

Answer (score 1):

### *[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/NbxDq/1/)*

```
<div class="main-content">
    <h2 class="header"> Header 1 </h2>     <!-- you can use h2 -->
    <div class="content"> lorum ipsum 1 </div>
    <div class="time"> time 1</div>
</div>
```

Just remove the padding from the container (`.content`) and play with  your children elements  padding.

```
.main-content {  
    
    position:relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    
    width: 80%;
    height: 50px;  
    
    background: rgb(251, 251, 251);
   
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.35);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);

    background-color: white;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;

}

h2.header, .content, .time{
    padding:3px 22px;
}
h2.header{   
    padding:13px 22px;
    font-size: 20px;    
    cursor:pointer;
}
.time{ padding-bottom:20px; }
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

### **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9UJ7f/19/)**

Here's the new javascript:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $(".news-item").click(function () {
        if( !$('.main-content', this).hasClass('expand') )
            $('.main-content', this).toggleClass("expand");
    });

    $('.news-item .main-content.expand .header').live('click',function () {
        $(this).parent().toggleClass("expand");
    });
});​
```

This does what you describe. It only expands an item if .news-item has no .expand class. If it does have one, then clicking the header is the only thing that will close it.

Answer (score 1):

Your js is correct. Change you css with

```
body {
    background-color: whitesmoke;
}

.header{
    font-size: 20px;
    cursor:pointer;
    padding: 22px 22px 20px 22px;
}

.content { padding: 0 22px; }
.time { padding: 0 22px; }

/* thanks to raingroove for the main styling ! */
.main-content {
    margin: 0 0 12px 70px;
    padding: 0;
    background: rgb(251, 251, 251);
    width: 80%;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.35);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
    position:relative;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    background-color: white;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    height: 66px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.expand {
    height: 200px;
}
```

see http://jsfiddle.net/9UJ7f/25/

Answer (score 1):

small addition to @thecodeparadox answer

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() 
   {
    $('.header').click(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation? e.stopPropagation() : e.cancelBubble = true; //e.stopPropagation() does not work for all browsers
        $(this).parent().toggleClass('expand');
    })
    $(".main-content").click(function() {
        if (!$(this).hasClass('expand')) {
            $(this).addClass("expand");
        }
    });
});
```